# Master contains changes from branch after merging master into branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge, revert

I recently created a branch, `branchA` off of `master` to develop a feature. While developing this feature, additional commits were pushed to `master`. I wanted to bring these changes into the branch, so while in `branchA`, I ran

```
git merge master
```

I then committed a change (B) on top of that. However, I later realized that I had merged the master into the branch poorly, so I reverted the commit using

```
git revert [hash of merge of master in branchA] -m 1
```

I then re-applied the changes from B, committing it. Finally,  I re-merged `master` into `branchA`.

I was satisfied with this merge, so I wanted to bring the changes from `branchA` into `master`. To my surprise, the changes were already in `master`. When I checked out the master and ran

```
git merge branchA
```

I saw

> Already up to date.

**What happened here?**

I come from an SVN background so I would have expected to need to merge `branchA` back into `master`, but it appears that seems to have happened automatically? Is this behavior related to fast-forwarding? And what if I didn't want this behavior to occur (i.e. to pull the changes in from the master into the branch without having the changes from the branch spill back into the master).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you pushed your branch to a remote yet? or is this local only?

Comment: @3D1T0R: I have pushed everything to remote already.

Comment: The tutorial at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing , under the "Merge Option" seems to indicate that merging the master into a branch will automatically make it so that the master points to the branch, if the histories meet a certain set of criteria?

Comment: [Read Linus Torvald's description of reverting a merge.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

Comment: @Anonymous: I don't see that in there at all. If you're looking at the "Merging master into the feature branch" image, and thinking it indicates that you're misunderstanding: The tip of master doesn't change at all when you merge it into your feature branch, you just bring over the changes. When another change is committed to the master branch it still won't have the changes from the feature branch.

Comment: @torek: Good read. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get a sense of what I did wrong. After I pushed the merged branch, I apparently accidentally initiated a merge of the branch into the trunk via the GUI (my first time using the GUI so I must have misclicked) and committed it. Thus when I went to the command line to merge the branch into the trunk there was nothing to do. I was confused because when I went to the GUI's history visualization, it showed the master's last commit was the same commit as the branch's last commit (merging master _into_ branchA), leading me to think it had somehow happened automatically. PEBCAK!

Comment: I'm still a little confused why, if my hypothesis is correct, why the merge from the branch into the master would result in the HEAD of the master also being the HEAD of the branch (and thus having a commit log message stating that it was a merge from the master _into_ the branch)--is this fast forwarding?

Comment: @Anonymous: yes, a fast-forward "merge" isn't actually a merge at all. It occurs when the target of the merge (the commit you're requesting to merge) is strictly ahead of the current (HEAD) commit. Without `--no-ff`, `git merge` says to itself: *aha, I can do that without actually merging, all I have to do is move this branch and thus `HEAD` forward and check out the other commit!*

Comment: "PEBCAK", I really do love that acronym.

Comment: @Anonymous To be picky - there is only one `HEAD`, which is a reference that points to either a branch (if one is currently checked out), or a commit (which is called a detached `HEAD`).  Each branch doesn't have its own `HEAD`, though I understand why you use this terminology...

Comment: By the way, which Git GUI are you using?

Comment: @LightCC: Thanks for the clarification on `HEAD`!  I just started using SourceTree in an effort to learn the GUI as well as the command line way of doing things.

Comment: @Anonymous I use Git Extensions, and find that a great short-cut most of the time, that allows a great visualization of what's going on, and easy access to all commits, plus great integration with the command-line, diff, merge, etc. when needed.  I haven't used SourceTree for comparison though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a `master` and `branchA`, both with a few commits each, and `branchA` is checked out (shown with *):

```
m1 - m2 - m3     <--- master
 \ 
  a1 - a2       <--- branchA*
```

*[**Edit:** Updated the merge result, per comments, to show that `master` doesn't move forward to the merge commit automatically]*

Then merge master into branchA, shown as merged commit a2m3:

```
m1 - m2 - m3        <-- master
 \          \ 
   a1 - a2 - a2m3   <-- branchA*
```

Revert of a merge just applies an "undo" of the changes, it doesn't undo the actual merge - shown as a2m3':

```
m1 - m2 - m3      <-- master
 \         \      
  a1 - a2 - a2m3 - a2m3' <-- branchA*
```

And since you did this revert with `branchA` still checked out, then `branchA` reference will be pointing to the new commit, and `master` ref is still pointing to the m3 commit.

You then added another commit:

```
m1 - m2 - m3      <-- master
 \         \      
  a1 - a2 - a2m3 - a2m3' - a3 <-- branchA*
```

Finally, when you checked out `master` and merged in `branchA`, as you guessed, it was just a fast forward, which forwarded `master` to point to the same commit as `branchA`. This was possible because the merge link from m3 to a2m3 was still present (the revert didn't remove it), so `master` is considered to be a parent commit of a3 (there is an unbroken chain to a3) and can just fast-forward to it.

```
m1 - m2 - m3  
 \         \      
  a1 - a2 - a2m3 - a2m3' - a3 <-- branchA / master*
```

This is the point where you tried to merge `branchA` into `master`, but got the response that it was "Already up to date".

Now, prior to the second merge attempt, if you had checked out `master` and committed at least once before merging in `branchA`, or someone else had committed to `master` on the remote and you pulled that down, then your branches would have diverged again (think of a new m4 commit to the right of m3). If that had happened, the merge from `branchA` into `master` would have been a full merge, rather than just a fast-forward.

---

## How to think about branches

The breakthrough for me on how to think about branches, is that a branch is really just a reference to a commit - and technically, all of the parent commits connected to it.  When you merge two branches, you are just creating a commit that has two parents, rather than one, and at that point there are not two branches, there is one - even the split series of commits that used to be separate `master` and `branchA`, are no longer separate - they have truly been merged and both branches refer to all of them now.

---

## What else could you have done?

Based on what I think you wanted to do, you could have done this:

**Warning: there are "Bad Things That Can Happen (tm)" if you change history after pushing up to a remote that Other People (tm) have access to... But at least in this case it would only be rewriting the `branchA` history, not `master`**

1. Rather than revert the merge of `master` into `branchA`, just reset `branchA` to the prior commit `a2`:

   > ```
   > git reset --hard <hash of a2>
   > ```

   Resetting like this removes all references to a2m3 so it effectively is removed from your repo. It will still be in your repo for a while, but there will be no way to get to it unless you saved the hash somewhere. Git tracks commits like this for a while, then garbage-collects and deletes them if they are not reused for long enough.
2. At this point you would have:

   > ```
   > m1 - m2 - m3   <-- master
   >  \
   >   a1 - a2      <-- branchA
   > ```

   Just like before the merge.

Comment: Amazing explanation! For the option under "What else could you have done", would that be using `reset` followed by a force push?
Also regarding how to think about branches, does this mean that merging BranchA->master is the same thing as merging master->branchA?

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks! To set to a prior commit (or any commit in the entire repo), you use the `reset` command, yes.  Google on the difference between soft, mixed, and hard resets.  A force push is needed at the end when you are ready to make your changes permanent on the remote - you don't need to push every time you change anything locally (in fact, while you are in the middle of making changes and haven't tested everything yet, you normally don't push, just keep everything local, unless someone needs access to your work).

Comment: @Anonymous For merging, no - if one is ahead of the other in the line of commits, then only the one that is behind can fast-forward (i.e. merge with the one that is ahead); actually, I'm not sure what it will say in the other direction, but an error of some kind or it will require a force flag.  In that situation, you are probably better off resetting directly to the desired commit to go backwards (keeping in mind the impact on remote users after this is pushed).  Also, don't go backwards without first tagging the lead commit or making a temp branch there, or you could lose access to it.

Comment: Okay, I'm slightly confused now, sorry! So in your second diagram, after running `git merge master`, assuming that I have branchA checked out, does the tip of the master and the tip of the branch both point to the same commit? In otherwords, if someone makes a commit to the master after that merge, will that new commit contain the changes from branchA?

Comment: I guess I'm just a little confused because in the second diagram, after the merge of master into branchA, master is now pointing to a2m3. I may be wrong, but I think it should be pointing to a2? At least that's what I seem to gather from what @3D1T0R was staying earlier in the question.

Comment: @Anonymous Your right! Just tested this and the branch that is merged in does not automatically move to the merge commit.  I went back and cleaned up everything based on that.  This actually makes your fixes are much cleaner.  If you had checked out `master` and made at least one more commit before merging `branchA` into it, then it would have been a normal merge, but since `master` was still at m3, it ended up being just a fast-forward. Should be all fixed up. [P.S. This is why I use Git Extensions so it shows me visually where all my branches and refs are... at all times... :) ]

Comment: Updated - though it happens after the "Finally" paragraph (rather than before it).  Good point - I added that and cleaned up the final paragraph in that section about what would have made it a full merge rather than a fast-forward.

Comment: Aha, thank you! And I'll have to check GIT Extensions out!